# How do I get Excel to Convert Local HTML paths in Column A to their respective images in Column B?

Tags: html, excel, image

First off, I'm not a programmer. I LOVE Excel and Access, but I am completely self-taught, and I shoot from the hip until I can get things to work as I want.

I've been searching the internet, trying to find the answer for rendering html paths to a local folder on my computer to the actual images that the paths represent. I have the html paths in Column A (called PhotoPath) and I'd like the image to be rendered in Column B (called Photo). My workbook is called Crystal_Specimens, and the worksheet is called Details.

I found the following code on this site...

```
<code>Dim url_column As Range
Dim image_column As Range

Set url_column = Worksheets(1).UsedRange.Columns("A")
Set image_column = Worksheets(1).UsedRange.Columns("B")

Dim i As Long
For i = 1 To url_column.Cells.Count

With image_column.Worksheet.Pictures.Insert(url_column.Cells(i).Value)
.Left = image_column.Cells(i).Left
.Top = image_column.Cells(i).Top
image_column.Cells(i).EntireRow.RowHeight = .Height
End With

Next</code>
```

...but I could not get it to work. I received several errors abut the Set url and Set image lines. Perhaps I don't know what parts of the code I actually need to change/customize to my specific project.

At any rate, if anyone could help me, it would be greatly appreciated. Thanks much!

Comment: `.Columns("A")` >> `.Columns(1)` etc

Comment: Thanks Tim. I made the changes, and I now receive the following error: "Unable to get the Insert property of the Picture class."

Comment: Can you provide an example of a path you're passing to `Insert` ?

Comment: I hope this is what you're requesting:

Comment: C:\Users\Scrappy\Documents\Scrappy's Stuff\Metaphysical\Crystal Specimen DB\Crystals Specimens Photos\07-001.jpg

Comment: Try instead `With image_column.Worksheet.Shapes.AddPicture(url_column.Cells(i).Value) `

Comment: Sorry for the delay. I've been checking regularly, but your last comment just showed up now, even though it says 3 hours ago.Now, I receive the error, "Argument not optional

Comment: UGH! I keep hitting the return to go to a new line and then the comment posts. I receive the error, "Argument not optional." It looks as though it's in reference to the .AddPicture portion of the code.

Comment: Sorry I missed the second argument:  `With image_column.Worksheet.Shapes.AddPicture(url_column.Cells(i)‌​.Value, False)`  - assuming you want to copy the picture into the workbook

Comment: ...actually looks like there are no optional arguments.  See: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff198302(v=office.14).aspx

Comment: So, should I change the second line?

Comment: Ah. So, your last comment means that my only option is to copy the picture into the workbook?? That is what I want, so that would be perfect. I'll give it a go.

Comment: See my code below...

Comment: Yeah, same error: "Argument not optional."

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Shapes.AddPicture` - the only tricky bit is you have to provide all of the arguments, including the width/height of the image, but if you pass in -1 for those it will use the actual size of the image.

```
Const MAX_HEIGHT As Long = 400
Dim c As Range, c2 As Range
Dim url_column
Dim i As Long, sht As Worksheet

Set sht = Worksheets(1)

Set url_column = sht.Range(sht.Range("A2"), _
                           sht.Cells(sht.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp))

For i = 1 To url_column.Cells.Count

    Set c = url_column.Cells(i)
    Set c2 = c.EntireRow.Cells(2)

    Debug.Print "Importing file '" & c.Value & "' ..." '<<< edit

    With sht.Shapes.AddPicture(c.Value, _
                   False, True, c2.Left, c2.Top, -1, -1)

        'shrink height if too large...
        If .Height > MAX_HEIGHT Then
            .LockAspectRatio = msoTrue 'shrink the width proportionally
            .Height = .Height * (MAX_HEIGHT / .Height)
        End If

        c.EntireRow.RowHeight = .Height
    End With
Next
```

Comment: Error, "The specified file wasn't found" in reference to this line of code: With image_column.Worksheet.Shapes.AddPicture(c.Value, _
                   False, True, c2.Left, c2.Top, -1, -1)

Comment: See my edit: check the output (in the Immediate pane of the VB Editor) is what you expect

Comment: Same error: "The specified file wasn't found" in reference to the same line of code. Output says, "Importing file 'PhotoPathTxt' ..." and PhotoPathTxt is the name of column containing the path to the image.

Comment: If you have a header then obviously that's going to cause an error.  Edited again above, to start at A2 instead...

Comment: Even with no programming expertise, I should have caught the header issue. Now, with reference to the same line of code, I receive the following error: "Object required." And I'm just going to put this out there: I'm willing to continue this, but if you're not, don't feel obligated. I've appreciated your help to this point.

Comment: My bad - that's what I get for editing in the page without testing.  Fixed and you should be good to go.

Comment: It's getting closer :). Error: Unable to set the row height property of the range class. Line of code: c.EntireRow.RowHeight = .Height

Comment: The image I used for my testing was fairly small: if your images are large then you may find you cannot resize the row height to match.  A bit of testing shows the maximum possible height is 409...

Comment: Is it possible to specify a width and have the height be variable to maintain aspect ratio?

Comment: Added a few lines to set the max height for any image.

Comment: Thank you so much. It is working. Now, I'm going to try out my skills to see if I can lock down size and aspect ratios a bit more. Much appreciated, Tim. :)